# Change Button Image in Actiobar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've imported a project containing `ActionBarSherlock Library`. Here is a method defined in the code below for setting `ActionBar`.

```
boolean isAddedToFav=false;
@Override
 public void setActionBar(ActionBar actBar) {
super.setActionBar(actBar);

_actionBar.removeAllActions();
_actionBar.addAction(new Action() {

    @Override
    public void performAction(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public int getDrawable() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!isAddedToFav)
            return R.drawable.bookmark2;
        else
            return R.drawable.bookmark;
    }
});}
```

Now I am confused about how this method gets called.Here `getDrawable()` sets an **image icon** to `Action Button` on `ActionBar`.Now I want to change this **icon image** when users clicks on this `ActionButton`.But I don't know how can i manually called the `getDrawable()`.
So please someone explain me about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a simple call this method where you want n change the Image according to your need in `getDrawable()`method

e.g `setActionBar(Your actionbar object)`

Hope this help to you!